# Links gone missing on Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issues in trying to fix a site that was built by some one else. Seems the previous developer some how used BootStrap which I'm not an expert. When checking the code I can see that there is a reference for a #footer class, but cannot find the exact problem. The problem is ... there are few Social Media icons, on the regular site they are click-able and working fine, but when you resize the site for responsive the images are there but the links disappear or not working ...

Any idea how to fix this problem ?

The site link is at : http://tie.com.sa/index.html

Thanks in advance ...

Fawaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some "priority" to the elements using `position: relative` and `z-index`.

The description of the footer is overlapping the icons.

Just add the properties and values as shown below into `#footer ul`:

```
#footer ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I have added the "priority" to the CSS now. Thanks for the advice. Fawaz

Comment: @FawazTaj Please start a new question if you have another issue. It isn't fair to Iago or useful to the site to have lengthy comment threads full of new questions.

Comment: RE: The answer, I wouldn't suggest going with a z-index of `9999` when `10` would do. Leave yourself room to go above or below it without having arbitrarily large numbers -- if nothing else, it's cleaner.

Comment: Hi Chriss, thanks for the advice, have removed my second question. Thanks again. Regards, Fawaz

Comment: Chris, i tried to put less than 9999, but this didn't work using chrome inspection.